# Survival plots with plotly

Tags: r, plotly, survival-analysis, r-plotly, survminer

there!
I try use package "plotly" to make interactive my survival curve, so for reproducible example, I use "lung" dataset:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(plotly)
sf_lung <- survival::survfit(survival::Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
p1 <- ggsurvplot(sf_lung, main = "Kaplan-Meier Curve for the NCCTG Lung Cancer Data")
plotly::ggplotly(p1)
```

And that error I get:

*Error in UseMethod("ggplotly", p) :
no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "c('ggsurvplot', 'ggsurv', 'list')"*

So what wrong?
my session info:
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22){...}
other attached packages:
survival_3.2-7  survminer_0.4.8 ggpubr_0.4.0    plotly_4.9.2.1  ggplot2_3.3.2

Comment: `ggplotly` doesn't know how to handle plots of that type since they aren't "normal" ggplots. Perhaps this package can help: https://github.com/jakeybob/plotly-survival or see the code here: https://plotly.com/python/v3/ipython-notebooks/survival-analysis-r-vs-python/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ggsurvplot created a list object. Use only the first item ("plot")
At least that works for me.

```
plotly::ggplotly(p1[[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks! work for me, but I still have one issue:  risk table, now its gone, and plotly don't recognize it